# large string vector to data.frame

Tags: r, data.table, rcpp, stringr

I have a large vector (100M elements) of words that are of the type:

```
words <- paste(letters,letters,letters,letters,sep="_")
```

(In actual data words are not all the same but all of length 8)

I would like to convert them to a data frame which has a column for each letter of the word and a row for each word. For this i have tried `str_split_fixed` and `rbind` on the result but on the large vector R freezes/takes forever.

so desired output of the form:

```
      l1    l2    l3    l4
1     a     a     a     a  
2     b     b     b     b
3     c     c     c     c
```

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Did you check the R based solution `do.call(rbind,strsplit(words,'_') )`?

Comment: @agstudy I edited my answer to comparing to this exact solution.

Comment: yes this is what i had tried agstudy thank you though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution:

- uses `paste()` to collapse the vector elements together
- uses `fread()` to parse the collapsed vector into data.table/data.frame

As a function:

```
collapse2fread <- function(x,sep) {

    require(data.table)
    fread(paste0(x,collapse="\n"),sep=sep,header=FALSE)
}
```

### Rcpp on top of that?

Could also try doing it in c++ via `Rcpp` packages to get more out of it? Something like:

```
std::string collapse_cpp(CharacterVector subject,const std::string collapseBy){

     int n = subject.size();
     std::string collapsed;

     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         collapsed += std::string(subject[i]) + collapseBy;
    }
    return(collapsed);
}
```

Then we get:

```
collapse_cpp2fread <- function(x,sep) {

    require(data.table)
    fread(collapse_cpp(x,collapse="\n"),sep=sep,header=FALSE)
}
```

### quick test for the cpp fxn

```
microbenchmark(
    paste0(words,collapse="\n"),
    collapse_cpp(words,"\n"),
    times=100)
```

not much but it's someting:

```
> Unit: microseconds
>                             expr   min     lq median     uq    max neval
>  paste0(words, collapse = "\\n") 7.297 7.7695  8.162 8.4255 33.824   100
>       collapse_cpp(words, "\\n") 4.477 5.0095  5.117 5.3525 17.052   100
```

### Comparison to strsplit method:

Make a more realistic input

```
words <- rep(paste0(letters[1:8], collapse = '_'), 1e5) # 100K elements
```

benchmark:

```
microbenchmark(
    do.call(rbind, strsplit(words, '_')),
    fread(paste0(words,collapse="\n"),sep="_",header=FALSE),
    fread(collapse_cpp(words,"\n"),sep="_",header=FALSE),
    times=10)
```

gives:

```
> Unit: milliseconds
>                                                               expr       min        lq    median                  uq
>                               do.call(rbind, strsplit(words, "_")) 782.71782 796.19154 822.73694 854.22211
> fread(paste0(words, collapse = "\\n"), sep = "_", header = FALSE)  62.56164  64.13504  68.22512  71.96075
> fread(collapse_cpp(words, "\\n"), sep = "_", header = FALSE)  47.16362  47.78030  50.12867  52.23102
>      max neval
> 863.0790    10
> 151.5969    10
> 109.9770    10
```

so about a 20x improvement at this size? hope it helps!

Comment: i don't know about rcpp but i will look into it, freed method worked though, and it has a progress meter! I added the tag for repp to question, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Expanding a bit on the Rcpp based solution. If you can assume the structure of the input, then it is easy to do it all in Rcpp with minimal copying of data.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List bazinga( CharacterVector txt, int nc ){
    int n = txt.size() ;

    std::vector<CharacterVector> columns(nc) ;
    for( int i=0; i<nc; i++){
        columns[i] = CharacterVector(n) ;    
    }

    std::string tmp ;
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++){
        const char* p = txt[i];
        for(int j=0; j<nc; j++){
            tmp = *p ;
            columns[j][i] = tmp ;
            p +=2 ;
        }
    }

    List out = wrap(columns) ;
    return out ;
}
```

I get:

```
> microbenchmark(f(), bazinga(words, 8), collapse2fread(words,
+     "_"), collapse_cpp2fread(words, "_"), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
                           expr       min        lq    median         uq          max neval
                            f() 830.21571 871.38955 899.07207 1001.18561   1299.15783    10
              bazinga(words, 8)  26.26454  30.61620  33.37360   46.24160     64.09243    10
     collapse2fread(words, "_")  59.96217  61.58535  67.20007   93.61615     97.85007    10
 collapse_cpp2fread(words, "_")  46.79471  48.58391  49.99636   82.69684    119.88587    10
```

Comment: i had to do as.data.table(bazinga(words,8)) to get what i want but it works well thank you! This doesn't work for words of the form 'a_ab_a_a' how would I modify to make this work? I tried changing p to `tmp.find("_",p)` but this doesn't work. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Unix-alike you should take advantage of the command line.  It's often faster to process large data there and then bring it into R once reduced.  Here, I write the `words` vector to file and then re-write it using Unix commands in the `system` R function.

```
> words <- rep(paste0(letters[1:8], collapse = '_'), 1e5)

> cat(words, file = 'out.txt', sep = '\n')
> write.table(system(' cat out.txt | tr "_" " " ', intern = TRUE),
              row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, 
              quote = FALSE, file = 'out.txt')

> head(read.table('out.txt'))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
# 1  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
# 2  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
# 3  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
# 4  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
# 5  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
# 6  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
```

And the typical R `do.call(rbind, ...)` method:

```
f <- function()
{
    x <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(words, '_'))
    y <- data.frame(x)
    names(y) <- paste0('l', ncol(y))
    return(y)
}

> microbenchmark(f())
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min      lq   median      uq      max neval
#   f() 818.2391 959.088 964.1105 989.081 997.8625   100
```

Comment: re-ran with your exact 100k/8 input and comparable values for base method now. updated answer to reflect this.